# Where can I download the basic server configurations for eclipse?

Tags: javascript, html, css, eclipse, web-applications

The docs say:

> Use the HTTP Preview server when you want to quickly test resources in a static Web project. The HTTP Preview server is a Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) embedded test server that is integrated with the workbench. It is intended for preliminary testing and saves you time to download, install, and set up an HTTP server. However, as your static Web project progresses through its development cycle you are encourage to test and run on an external HTTP server. You can use the HTTP Preview server as a convenient way to check for errors before you do a final test on an external HTTP server.
>
> To create and test on an HTTP Preview server for previewing your resources in a static Web project, complete the following steps:
> In the Servers view, right-click and select New > Server. The Define a New Server wizard opens.
> Under the Select the server type list, expand the Basic folder and select HTTP Preview. Click Next.

....

When I follow these steps I have no basic folder. Is there somewhere I can download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use MAMP instead.

http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

And firebug for debugging.

https://getfirebug.com/dom